# How can I reach the second word in a string?

Tags: c++, char

I'm new here and this is my first question, so don't be too harsh :]

I'm trying to reverse a sentence, i.e. every word separately.
The problem is that I just can't reach the second word, or even reach the ending of a 1-word sentence. What is wrong?

```
char* reverse(char* string)
{
    int i = 0;
    char str[80];
    while (*string)
        str[i++] = *string++;
    str[i] = '\0'; //null char in the end
    char temp;
    int wStart = 0, wEnd = 0, ending = 0; //wordStart, wordEnd, sentence ending
    while (str[ending]) /*@@@@This part just won't stop@@@@*/
    {
        //skip spaces
        while (str[wStart] == ' ')
            wStart++; //wStart - word start
        //for each word
        wEnd = wStart;
        while (str[wEnd] != ' ' && str[wEnd])
            wEnd++; //wEnd - word ending
        ending = wEnd; //for sentence ending 
        for (int k = 0; k < (wStart + wEnd) / 2; k++) //reverse
        {
            temp = str[wStart];
            str[wStart++] = str[wEnd];
            str[wEnd--] = temp;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Can use use a `stringstream`? If not, why not?

Comment: you may want to add a `c` tag to this, code looks like pure c

Comment: @RedAlert: It's also pure C++.

Comment: I'd try going through the program with the Debugger and see where it cracks and what value/maybe error it returns.

Comment: @KeithThompson true, it's already tagged as `c++` though

Comment: My guess is that `for (int k = 0; k < (wStart + wEnd) / 2; k++)` doesn't do what you think because `wStart` and `wEnd` are modified inside the loop. Running in a debugger is the correct thing to do though, or even just print some of the values to see which one(s) are not as expected.

Comment: @RedAlert: No point in tagging it as both. The tag should correspond to the language the OP is actually compiling. There are subtle differences between C and C++, though they probably don't apply here; no need to complicate things by asking about both languages.

Comment: Unrelated, but you are returning the value of a local variable, `str`. This will cause you problems. `prog.cpp:6:10: warning: address of local variable 'str' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     char str[80];`

Comment: So I tried running this in a debugger and the problem seems to be here:
     while (str[wEnd] != ' ' && str[wEnd])
   wEnd++;

->this loop doesn't stop

Comment: Please see my answer below.  I think a debugger for this is like a sledge-hammer for an ant.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is somewhat unidiomatic for C++ in that it doesn't actually make use of a lot of common and convenient C++ facilities. In your case, you could benefit from

- [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) which takes care of maintaining a buffer big enough to accomodate your string data.
- [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) which can easily split a string into spaces for you.
- [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) which can reverse a sequence of items.

Here's an alternative version which uses these facilities:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::string reverse( const std::string &s )
{
    // Split the string on spaces by iterating over the stream
    // elements and inserting them into the 'words' vector'.
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::istringstream stream( s );
    std::copy(
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>( stream ),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
        std::back_inserter( words )
    );

    // Reverse the words in the vector.
    std::reverse( words.begin(), words.end() );

    // Join the words again (inserting one space between two words)
    std::ostringstream result;
    std::copy(
        words.begin(),
        words.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>( result, " " )
    );
    return result.str();
}
```

Comment: This isn't really answering the question:  it wasn't "please rewrite me something correct" as I understood it.  It was "please help me understand what's wrong with this chunk of code".

Comment: @ThomasKammeyer Maybe - when I started writing this answer, the question was titled 'C++ basic: How can I reach the 2nd. word in a string?' and said 'I'm trying to reverse a sentence, i.e. every word separately.'. I first considered doing what you did (debugging the given code) but then thought that *that* isn't an answer - because that's not how you would reverse a string word-wise in C++ anyway. I think both answers are useful.

Comment: I didn't debug it.  I read it.  I'm not being snarky.  I just think it's an important distinction that the profession is losing, so I'm taking the opportunity to make this point in this one tiny corner of the web.

Comment: @ThomasKammeyer As far as I can see, you clearly read and thought about the code. Which, to me, is the very essence of debugging. :-) I understand where you are coming from - my answer was written based on the understanding that the OP would like to know how to reverse a string word-wise in C++. I believe answering that question should mention `std::reverse` somewhere because, well, that's how you reverse sequences of things in C++. You're right though, maybe the question was actually "Why doesn't this code work." and I missed it.

Comment: Well, not to be pedantic, but to be pedantic:  he said "every word separately", which is what his code appears to be attempting even though it's got bugs.  That's not the same as reversing the sentence word-wise.

Comment: @ThomasKammeyer By now I wonder whether I misunderstood the question. It starts with `I'm trying to reverse a sentence`, which made me think that the order of the words is going to change. That's clearly not what his code (attempts to) do, it keeps the order of the words but reverses the letters of each word. I inferred the desired behaviour from the English text (or my flawed understanding of it) instead of the code. Maybe I should delete my answer to avoid confusing things...

Comment: You could also just modify to do the task that it looks like he's trying to perform.  I buy your earlier point that it's useful to have it here as well.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the first word, after it's traversed, str[wEnd] is a space and
you remember this index when you assign ending = wEnd.
Immediately, you reverse the characters in the word.  At that point,
str[ending] is not a space because you included that space in the
letter-reversal of the word.

Depending on whether there are extra
spaces between words in the rest of the input, execution varies from this point, but it does eventually end with
you reversing a word that ended at the null terminator on the string
because you end the loop that increments wEnd on that null terminator and
include it in the final word reversal.

The very next iteration walks off of
the initialized part of the input string and the execution is undetermined from there because, heck, who knows what's in that array (str is stack-allocated, so it's whatever's sitting around in the memory occupied by the stack at that point).

On top of all of that, you don't update wStart except in the reversal loop,
and it never moves to wEnd all the way (see the loop exit condition), so come to think of it, you're never getting past that first word.  Assuming that was fixed, you'd still have the problem I outlined at first.

All this assumes that you didn't just send this function something longer than 80 characters and break it that way.

Oh, and as mentioned in one of the comments on the question, you're returning stack-allocated local storage, which isn't going to go anywhere good either.

Comment: Thanks! You really helped, everybody else too [I didn't mention I'm a begginer, my bad...]. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hoo, boy. Where to start?

In C++, use `std::string` instead of `char*` if you can.

`char[80]` is an overflow risk if `string` is input by a user; it should be dynamically allocated. Preferably by using `std::string`; otherwise use `new` / `new[]`. If you meant to use C, then `malloc`.

cmbasnett also pointed out that you can't actually return `str` (and get the expected results) if you declare / allocate it the way you did. Traditionally, you'd pass in a `char* destination` and not allocate anything in the function at all.

<strike>Set `ending` to `wEnd + 1`; `wEnd` points to the last non-null character of the string in question (eventually, if it works right), so in order for `str[ending]` to break out of the loop, you have to increment once to get to the null char.</strike> Disregard that, I misread the while loop.

It looks like you need to use `((wEnd - wStart) + 1)`, not `(wStart + wEnd)`. Although you should really use something like `while(wEnd > wStart)` instead of a `for` loop in this context.

You also should be setting `wStart = ending;` or something before you leave the loop, because otherwise it's going to get stuck on the first word.